# How to redirect all .html pages from folders and subfolders to main language subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to make a .htaccess 301 redirect **to get the next results**.

**Original URL**
example.com/en/pageX.html
example.com/fr/pageX.html
**Final URL**
example.com/en/pageX.html
example.com/fr/pageX.html

At the same time:

**Original URL**
example.com/en/X/pageX.html
example.com/fr/X/pageX.html
**Final URL**
example.com/en/pageX.html
example.com/fr/pageX.html

And also at the same time:

**Original URL**
example.com/en/X/X/pageX.html
example.com/fr/X/X/pageX.html
**Final URL**
example.com/en/pageX.html
example.com/fr/pageX.html

And also at the same time:

**Original URL**
example.com/en/X/X/X/pageX.html
example.com/fr/X/X/X/pageX.html
**Final URL**
example.com/en/pageX.html
example.com/fr/pageX.html

For example and summarizing:

**Original URL**
example.com/en/food.html
example..com/fr/nourriture.html
example..com/en/food/fruits.html
example.com/fr/nourriture/fruits.html
example.com/en/food/fruits/apples.html
example.com/fr/nourriture/fruits/pommes.html
example.com/en/food/fruits/apples/apple_golden.html
example.com/fr/nourriture/fruits/pommes/pomme_golden.html
**Final URL**
example.com/en/food.html
example.com/fr/nourriture.html
example.com/en/fruits.html
example.com/fr/fruits.html
example.com/en/apples.html
example.com/fr/pommes.html
example.com/en/apple_golden.html
example.com/fr/pomme_golden.html

Thank you for your help.

Josep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite to remove all folders between the language identifier the actual page name and redirect the browser to show the new url. See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/.*?([^/]+\.html)$ $1/$2 [R,L]
```

This rule matches the language tag at the beginning of the path with `^(en|fr)` and puts it in capture group 1. We then match a slash and as little characters as possible (`/.*?`). Finally it matches the page name with `([^/]+\.html)$` and puts it in capture group 2. Finally we put the url back together by using group substitution (`$1` and `$2`) and forcing a temporary redirect with the `[R]` flag. When the rule works as expected, you can change the redirect flag to `[R=301]` to make it a permanent redirect. Permanent redirects are cached by the browser, preventing useless requests to the server and forcing sites like google to index it as if the two urls are the same page.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, but I have two problems. If I use your RewriteRule the result was:  "example.com/home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/en/food.html"  and if I add a slash **before** $1 in your code, the result was correct, but the browser say: Error:Too many connections.

Comment: Do you have a non-standard setup for your Apache? I think your document root may not be set correctly, or that you have more rules than this one, and that conflicts. I am unsure what the "Too many connections" error is. Do you mean "Too many redirects"?

Comment: Yes, I have more rules and I mean "Too many redirects" I'm sorry. Is there any way that this rule prevails over the others or that it executes this in the first place? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try to put all your redirects before any rule that is an internal rewrite. You are likely seeing the result of an internal rewrite being processed before the redirect takes place. The `[L]` flag only ends the current rewrite run, and does not end rewriting altogether.